# Bitbucket Pipeline deploy to Elasticbeanstalk - Upload issue - No changes reflected

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

Guys I am having issues deploying to elasticbeanstalk. It seems that when running the pipeline it just duplicates the existing zip file within the s3 bucket. Tried various scenarios but still get the same result.

```
    image: node:10.15.1

    pipelines:
      default:
     - step:
            name: EBS deployment
            deployment: test
   script:
    - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.5
    variables:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
    APPLICATION_NAME: 'applicationXYZ'
    COMMAND: 'upload-only'
    ENVIRONMENT_NAME: 'Test'
    ZIP_FILE: 's3://applicationXYZ-elasticbeanstalk-deployment/applicationXYZ-app.zip'
    S3_BUCKET: 'applicationXYZ-elasticbeanstalk-deployment'
    DEBUG: 'TRUE'
```

I run the pipeline with success but the new file created in the bucket is exactly the same as the old one but with different version name. I checked to see if the changes that I have made have been reflected in the new zip file but unfortunately it is identical to the original zip.

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.2.5

INFO: Uploading to s3 bucket: applicationXYZ-elasticbeanstalk-deployment...

Completed 680.3 KiB/32.7 MiB (860.5 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining

Completed 8.7 MiB/32.7 MiB (9.7 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining Completed 16.7 MiB/32.7 MiB (17.5 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining Completed 24.7 MiB/32.7 MiB (24.6 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining Completed 32.7 MiB/32.7 MiB (30.7 MiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining

copy: s3://applicationXYZ-elasticbeanstalk-deployment/applicationXYZ-app.zip to s3://applicationXYZ-elasticbeanstalk-deployment/applicationXYZ-102-eb15a3fd.zip

✔ Artifact uploaded successfully to s3://applicationXYZ-elasticbeanstalk-deployment/applicationXYZ-102-eb15a3fd.zip
```

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0):

`S3` has a [versioning system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) (check if is not activated) if the file uploaded has the same name `S3` create a version of it none a new file.
As a hack and to check if the file is correctly uploaded try to rename it (add a timestamp for example)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Yes versioning is enabled and the file uploaded has the same name.

If I change the name (from applicationXYZ-app.zip to applicationXYZ-app-eb15a3fd.zip) the pipeline fails:

fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "applicationXYZ-app.zip" does not exist

Comment: You're trying to create this: "applicationXYZ-app-eb15a3fd.zip" and you get "Key "applicationXYZ-app.zip" does not exist" that's wired